# Image uploading message is red after failed upload:

Tags: bug, design, uploader

When I upload an image that is invalid, I get some red text:

> [image]

Then when I upload a valid image, the Uploading text is red:

> [image]

<sup>(Note that the 3 dots do appear, this screen shot was just badly timed).</sup>

When it is normally grey:

> [image]

The only reason is because the text has been changed, as has the colour, but the colour is not changed back.

Comment: Does it work though?

Comment: @Milo Yes it does still upload.